# Can you use a mining hardware to find a string for a certian hash

Tags: mining-hardware, sha256

Using a computer to brute force a sha256 will take very long time, but with a mining hardware, it still takes long, but at least chances of finding it are better.
But the question is, are mining hardware designed to only work for crypto-currency mining and cannot be programmed to search for a specific hash?